# what is the correct reading for this kanji

Tags: kanji

I can't find this kanji in the dictionary jsho. I tried all given readings in the dictionary.
What does it mean ? 
Question nr 9

Thanks a lot

[image: question 9]

Updated: without I at the end could not find

Comment: 「安い」の「安」、「安全」の「安」

Comment: Are you sure you can't find it on jisho? Look here https://jisho.org/search/安い

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やすい。安い。

It is literally given in the options. You could have just tried them all.

It means :

1. Cheap, Inexpensive
2. Calm, Peaceful, Quiet